# Sencha Extjs 6 build output directory - Microloader configuration

Tags: extjs, build, manifest, extjs6, sencha-cmd

Currently i am trying to migrate an extjs 5 application to 6.2.
It was a tough time but after couple of hours it runs fine. Also sencha app build works fine with the default configuration. Application works fine.

But we have to change the path to the generated html file. We are doing some processing in our framework and add variables to the extjs index.html
Our file structure looks like

- /

  - /my/app/index.html (generated by server, should load the bootloader from extjs)
  - /compiled/extjs-app/*X.all-extjs-production-build-files.X* // like app.json, cache.appcache etc

The problem is that i can't make the micro loader working with this structure. I tried several setting within the app.json in my application workspace but nothing worked. Was tweaking the output.base, output.page.path variables and so on. Trying with included and external microloader but can't get it to work. Was already having difficulties with extjs 5 but now it seems even more unhandy as the whole caching come into play. The documentation on this topic is poor. I think a lot of people generate their application html page over a server side language and then use the loader to make their app working. Why can't we just specify a local path to store the files and independently define a "path" for loading. This would be used by the micro loader to generate the required paths?!

My impression is that the microloader is not aware of the paths. Based on the html page url he tries to determine the resources paths. I was trying a lot and have no further idea.

Has someone solved this struggle? Any hint would be highly welcome.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: We did the same thing, ran into similar issues. I can't say it's exactly the same.  Look at local storage, some files are stored in there. So they bypass your changes.  Unminify bootstrap.json and see where your files point to (towards the bottom).

Comment: I just tested one more thing.

Comment: `"output": {
        "base": "${workspace.dir}/compiled/app-${build.environment}-build/dist",
        "page": {
            "path"  :   "../../../my/app/index.html",
            "enable":   true
        }
        , "microloader": {
            "path": "microloader.js",
            "embed": true,
            "enable": true
        }
        , "appCache":{
            "enable": false
        }
    },` which works when i remove the "Ext.beforeLoad = function (tags)..." from the generated index.html. We are having  a plain classic app. For what is that modern/classic switch?

Comment: Thanks Coupon rabais. With bootstrap.json you mean the app.json?

Comment: The bootstrap.json is generated partly from app.json. Usually in the root with app.json.

Comment: Weird. I don't have any bootstrap.json in cmd 6.2.x